# Correct way to specify and retrieve project version (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, properties

I am using Gradle to build my application and I want to know the best way to **specify** and **retrieve** the application version.

I've seen suggestions to put it in either `gradle.properties`:

```
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

or `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    group = 'com.my-app'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Which of these two options is the best?

How do I then retrieve the version at runtime?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(****retrieve version number here****); 
}
```

I've read around various posts but I'm not seeing a solution.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that put property into `gradle.properties` is the best way, because it is configuration file for your project designed to store variables. You can get property in runtime if you know path to `gradle.properties` file:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File fileProps = new File("yout/path", "gradle.properties");
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(fileProps));
    String version = properties.getProperty("version");
    System.out.println("Version = " + version); 
}
```